# Two Mercurial repos. on remote machine -- one is cloneable via ssh; the other, not

Tags: ssh, mercurial, clone

On my LAN, on a remote machine `people` there are two Mercurial repositories in my home directory:  *Documents* and *stage*.  Just to be quite clear:  these two subdirectories are each a Mercurial repository and they are peers of one another on the same machine.

When on another machine I run `hg clone ssh://people:3887/Documents`, the repository is cloned as expected.  When I run `hg clone ssh://people:3887/stage` the response is:

```
remote: abort: error: node name or service name not known
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

What could be different about these two repositories that means that one is cloneable and the other not?  On the local machine itself, as the same user as which I am sshing, I can run all the usual `hg` commands without problems in either repository.  I can't see anything obvious in the permissions on the two repositories, including on the files in `.hg/` and in any case, I can do all Mercurial operations locally as the same user.

Comment: I tried this on the host machine:  `cp -a stage S1` then on the remote machine:  `hg clone ssh://people:3887/S1` and it worked.  However, `hg clone ssh://people:3887/S1 stage` returned

    _abort: cannot create new http repository_

although there is no such file or directory yet in existence on the remote machine.  `hg clone ssh://192.168.0.3:3887/stage S0` also returns

    _remote: abort: error: node name or service name not known_
    _abort: no suitable response from remote hg!_

So it seems there is something special about the name `stage`.

Comment: What OS is the ssh server? Was this like a Unix vs Windows case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: Gentoo Linux.  No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by renaming *stage* to *Stage* on the host machine. The repository can then be cloned as normal.